# Python json can load while Chrome Dev tools can't

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-chrome

My server side application successfully loaded this JSON string, while Chrome raise exception when loading it.

JSON String like `{\"key\":\"Emilian !\"}`

Python:

`json.loads("{\"key\":\"Emilian !\"}")`

`{u'key': u'Emilian\u2028!'}`

Chrome Dev Tools:

`JSON.parse("{\"key\":\"Emilian !\"}")`

`JSON.parse("{\"key\":\"Emilian`

```
           `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
```

`SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

How can I make python behave like Chrome, raise an exception? Or make Chrome load JSON like python.

Comment: It doesn't like the line separator within the string. If you delete the character between the n and the ! it should work

Comment: Python usually used UTF-8 as encoding, Javascript UTF-16. In other words: Your string is invalid in Javascript. You can even remove the `JSON.parse()` to get the same effect.

Comment: That's true, but why Python can load while Chrome can't ? I use Python module json to do some verification on that JSON response, and returned to client.

Comment: @KlausD. That makes sense, thanks a lot